# Get string backwards using for loop, Python

Tags: for-loop, python-3.x

I found this previously answered here, [Best way to loop over a python string backwards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961499/best-way-to-loop-over-python-string-backward)

I need to use OP's original idea, but I don't quite understand the meaning of the stop argument in the range function. What does 0-1 mean? From 0-1? Wouldn't that be the step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why can't you use reversed as accepted in the previously answered question?

However, to answer your original question:

The 0-1 is actually just a number 0-1, which is equal to -1

The documentation for range says the following: `range(start[, end[, step]])`. His call looks like the following: `range(len(string)-1, 0-1, -1)`

**start** = `len(string)-1`, which is last letter of the string.

**end** = `0-1` which is equal to `-1`, so the last letter being handled is `0`. Remember that `range(0, 3)` will actually give `0, 1, 2` and stop right before the `3`. Same goes for negative numbers, it will stop right before `-1`, so it will stop at `0`.

**step** = `-1`. Step stands for how many numbers to step over at once. `-1` means it will lower `i` by one every time.

Comment: Thank you. Because assignment says specifically not to use reveresed. If end was 0-1 to mean -1, why not just type -1?

Comment: @algebr That question, I am unable to answer. He probably saw it somewhere and just copy-pasted without thinking of the meaning. It doesn't have any impact on the execution of the program. `0-1` **is the same as** `-1`, so you should indeed type `-1` instead.

Answer (score 1):

The 0-1 is -1, it can be written either way:

```
>>> -1
-1
>>> 0-1
-1
```

Let's try a string length of 10, stop of 0-1 ad step of -1:

```
>>> range(10, 0-1, -1)
[10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

you'll see the same result with -1 instead of 0-1:

```
>>> range(10, -1, -1)
[10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

The step of -1 causes range to count backward, let's try a step of 1:

```
>>> range(10, 0-1, 1)
[]
```

When in doubt, shell it out